# Update a jQuery script when user switches to a new tabbed element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time describing exactly what the problem is.. but the link in question is: http://www.evolutionarycollective.com/events/

You'll notice that when you load the "Calendar" tab, the calendar doesn't show up. If you resize the window, or manipulate the page in some other way, then the calendar appears. The calendar loads fine when it's not within a tab. It's being called in the header with:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: themeforce.events
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:
I believe this is the section of the script library that handles the tabs and panes.. (I'm using this with a wordpress theme that calls the tabs via a shortcode)

```
    // jQuery tool's tab creator is not shortcode friendly, transfer the titles to the correct tabs area
    jQuery('.bfi_pane').each(function(i) {
        var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        jQuery(jQuery(this).siblings('.bfi_tabs,.bfi_tabs_slide,.bfi_tabs_fade')[0]).append('<div><a href="#">'+title+'</a></div>');
    });

    // Custom slide effect for tabs. slide up then down
    jQuery.tools.tabs.addEffect('slide-slide',function(i, done) { 
        this.getPanes().slideUp(400).eq(i).delay(400).slideDown(400, done);           
    });
    // Custom slide effect for tabs. slide up and down simultaneously
    jQuery.tools.tabs.addEffect("slide", function(i, done) {
        this.getPanes().slideUp(400).eq(i).slideDown(400, done);
    });

    // IMPORTANT: SLIDEDOWN JQUERY FIX. we need to assign the correct heights
    // so that the slidedown effect doesn't JUMP
    jQuery(".bfi_accordion_pane").each(function(i) {
        var heightTo = jQuery(this).height();
        var paddingTop = parseInt(jQuery(this).css("padding-top").replace('px', ''));
        var paddingBottom = parseInt(jQuery(this).css("padding-bottom").replace('px', ''));
        var marginTop = parseInt(jQuery(this).css("margin-top").replace('px', ''));
        var marginBottom = parseInt(jQuery(this).css("margin-bottom").replace('px', ''));
        jQuery(this).css("height", heightTo + paddingTop + paddingBottom + marginTop + marginBottom);
    });

    // start jQuery tool tabs. we have to do this the long way so we can make
    // initialIndex work properly
    jQuery(".bfi_tabs_slide").each(function(i) {
        var openTab = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery(this).tabs('> div.bfi_pane', {effect: 'slide-slide', initialIndex: parseInt(openTab, 10)});
    });
    jQuery(".bfi_tabs_fade").each(function(i) {
        var openTab = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery(this).tabs('> div.bfi_pane', {effect: 'fade', initialIndex: parseInt(openTab, 10)});
    });
```

Is there some way I can somehow refresh the script when that tab lis loaded.. or fire off another document.ready?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post up the code you're using for the tabs? (Presuming you're doing it with JS).

Comment: Yeah, you probably want the fullCalendar function call to be made when the calendar tab show event fires, not by firing off another document.ready

Comment: I've added the script that handles the tabs

Answer (score 1):

The probable explanation is that the full calendar can't figure out its height because when initially created that tab is hidden, which will make it have zero width and height.

Just make the call to `.fullCalendar()` in a tab switch event handler.

Alternatively use the "off-left" method of hiding tabs, as described in the last few paragraphs of http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: This could work.. ideally I'd like to be able to use the tabs shortcode elsewhere on the site. If the .fullCalendar() call was in the tab code, it would be called on every page that used tabs.. correct?

Comment: Just use the 'off-left' method, then.